# Retorno de dados PHP + Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Olá,

No meu sistema pretendo que, ao usuário selecionar os dados presentes dentro dos dropdowns e clicar em confirmar, o valor selecionado vai para o documento `filtraDashboardGeral.php`, com uma função PHP faz o `SELECT` na minha tabela, retorna o resultado utilizando o valor do método `POST` como parâmetro e o retorno dessa função seja inserido nas variáveis que já tenho na minha página principal, é possível?

Meu script:

```
$("#botao-filtrar").click(function(){
    $(".mask-loading").fadeToggle(1000);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {rede: $("#dropdown-parceria").val()},
    })
    .done(function(resposta){
        console.log(resposta);
    })
    .always(function(){
        $(".mask-loading").fadeToggle(1000);
    })
});
```

Meu documento `filtraDashboardGeral.php`:

```
<?php
    $rede = $_POST['rede'];

    function buscaDados($conexao){
        $dados = array();

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM evolucao_originacao WHERE rede = {$rede}");

        while($valores = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
            array_push($dados, $valores);
        }
    }

foreach ($dados as $filtrados) :
    $_SESSION['redeAtual'] = $dados['rede'];
endforeach
```

> Resumidamente, quero alterar o valor das minhas variáveis de sessão por meio de uma requisição Ajax, sendo que são variáveis de sessão, é possível?

Grato.

Comment: Sim é possível, dá algum erro?

Comment: @Miguel, na verdade, eu não sei como retornar os valores que eu peguei no filtro para dentro das minhas variaveis

Comment: João mas não dá nenhum erro, certo? Apenas quer retornar `$dados['rede']` de volta para o lado cliente? PS: esta linha: `$_SESSION['redeAtual'] = $dados['rede'];` , não está a fazer sentido, está a reescrever o valor da variável `$_SESSION['rede']` a cada loop

Comment: @Miguel, dá erro 500. (editei o meu script para tentar exibir alguma coisa mas nada, alterei no post). Esta foi a única forma que veio a cabeça para setar a variável com o valor do array

Comment: @Miguel segue erro http://imgur.com/VXwOjJD

Comment: Não é esse erro que quero ver, é o erro do lado servidor, d3eves ter um erro no php. Precisas de ver esta tab: https://postimg.org/image/3s3fa533b/ . Network->all->response , e clicas em `filtraDashboardGeral.php` do lado esquerdo

Comment: @Miguel segue https://postimg.org/image/k1o1elv45/ o php n retorna nenhum erro

Comment: João do lado esquerdo, na lista das requisições que são feitas à de lá estar (quando fizer o pedido ajax) o ficheiro `filtraDashboardGeral.php` , clicque em cima dele quando aparecer e em `response`

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/wgl5j4km7/ agora apareceu

Comment: Ok, bom agora clique na tab response em vez de "headers" . Esperemos que tenha os erros de php habilitados

Comment: @Miguel sem nenhum erro na aba de response, diz que não há dados disponiveis

Comment: Ok, então agora coloque no lado servidor (php) `echo 'olá';` depois do foreach, faz isso de novo e vê a response

Comment: Failed to load response data

Comment: Isso apareceu onde? na response?

Comment: @Miguel foi sim.

Comment: Voce nao precisa colocar a função do arquivo php no teu requisição?  `'datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php/funcao'`